# Uploadify swf js error on page load with cancelled status

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, flash, uploadify

I am using uploadify plugin in my magento site for uploading the files and i am getting the following error on pageload and i googled for this error but i am not able to get why the call is happening 2 times and getting cancelled in **Google Chrome** only?

```
https://mysite.com/skin/frontend/mytheme/default/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf
```

On page load this call is happening 2 times and how can i resolve this js error(functionality is working fine) and my code

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'   : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'     : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'folder'     : 'upload'
});
```

And if i observe the call logs in Network(chrome browser) its showing

```
uploadify.swf
/skin/frontend/mytheme/default/js/uploadify   GET   (canceled)  Pending  jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2Script 13 B0 B 13 ms
-
uploadify.swf
/skin/frontend/mytheme/default/js/uploadify   GET   (canceled)  Pending   jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2Script 13 B0 B 13 ms
```

And i observed that it's the issue from uploadify plugin itself because the demo url also showing the same cancelled requests [Demo Url](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) in call log. But my client don't want these type of requests.

In newer version of Google chrome it's giving the error in request headres like **"CAUTION: provisional headers are shown”**

[image]

So could you please help me to sort out (or) **the reason for canceling the requests**?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your reply and i have updated my question please look above and it's not an error but my client don't want this kind of display

Comment: That is an odd place to serve up the Uploadify SWF from, but ignoring that, can you directly browse that SWF URL? (ie. is the file accessible there?)

Comment: Yes If i try to access the url directly then i am getting the blank page only.

Comment: yeah, it's accessible i think, since it's giving options of adobe flash player when right click on document

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, started a bounty

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with swfobject.

Anyways I was able to prevent it by wrapping a div around my upload button and having it display:none and then once the I used JQuery to uploadify I ran .show() on the hidden div. My assumption is that chrome only loads when display isn't none so if you trigger it after the uploadify() has ran it works.

This is still a hack and I don't know what is the real cause.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem exactly : loading the swf file 3 times with 2 failed or the upload button (which should be the swf) didn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload your code somewhere, so I can test this issue ?

Some suggestions:

1) try to use the absolute path like: 
from

```
'uploader'   : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
```

to

```
 'uploader'   : 'https://example.com/folder/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
```

2) try to access the file on http:// instead https://
3) give read/write permission to the swf file